# Physics Homework - Final Velocity

Tags: physics, projectile-motion

So I'm doing my physics homework and I need some help on finding some answers. It's the last three questions on my sheet and I can't seem to get my head around it.

A ball is projected at $20\ m/s$ from the top of a $150\ m$ cliff. I need to calculate the **Time Taken** to hit the water at the bottom. **Distance Travelled Horizontally** and the **Final Velocity.** - This is an extension task I've never seen before and I don't want to give this up. How do I go about working this out?

Comment: This is for math problems... not physics. Try physics forums dot com. Good luck!

Comment: What direction does the ball start at?  What limits its travel distance?

Comment: @MarkWatson: I am personally of the opinion that almost all physics questions can be asked on this site and still fall within the guidelines...

Comment: @abiessu You are far more experienced than I: perhaps I should reconsider my position. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: This is a mathematical question insofar as it is basic applied maths for projectile motion. However the OP needs to state the angle of projection., not just the initial speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS: Using second equation of motion $$h=ut+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
setting $h=150\ m$, $u=20\ m/s$ & $g=10\ m/s^2$
we get $$t^2+4t-30=0$$
Find the time taken $t>0$ then 
$$\text{horizontal distance}=u_xt=20t$$
vertical component of velocity $v_y=u_yt+gt=10t$
The horizontal velocity $u_x=20\ m/s$ remains constant i.e. not affected by the gravity.

Hence the final velocity
$$=\sqrt{(u_x)^2+(v_y)^2}=\sqrt{20^2+(10t)^2}$$

Comment: Your first equation for the vertical component of velocity assumes that the initial vertical component of velocity is 20. You are then assuming that the horizontal component of velocity is also 20. Is this what the question is saying?

Comment: No, only horizontal component is $u_x=20\ m/s$ but the vertical component is $u_y=0$ as projected in horizontal direction from a height $h=150\ m$ on the cliff. If both vertical & horizontal components are equal to $20\ m/s$ then angle of projection will be $45^\circ$ which is not given

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint:

The vertical and horizontal movement can be computed independently.
The vertical one is a free fall and the horizontal one has constant speed.